# JPA/Hibernate entity relation synchronization

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Situation:

- I have an entity `Project` owning a relation to `User`:

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table
> public class Project {
>
>     @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
>     @JoinTable(name = "FOLLOWS",
>         joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")},
>         inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")})
>     private Set<User> followers = new HashSet<>();
>
>     public void removeFollower(User user) {
>         if (followers.contains(user)) {
>             user.getProjectsFollowed().remove(this);
>             followers.remove(user);
>         }
>     }
>     ... (getters, setters, equals, hashCode)
> }
> ```

- my `ProjectService` contains the `deleteProject` method

> ```
> @Service
> public class ProjectService {
>     @Transactional
>     public void deleteProject(Project project)  {
>         project.getFollowers().forEach(project::removeFollower);
>         projectRepo.delete(project);
>     }
> }
> ```

- also my `ProjectRepository`:

> ```
> @Repository
> public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, BigDecimal> {}
> ```

- on the other side I have the `User` declaring the relation towards the `Project`:

> ```
> @Entity
> @Data
> public class User {
>     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "followers")
>     private Set<Project> projectsFollowed = new HashSet<>();
>     ... (getters, setters, equals, hashCode)
> }
> ```

Now I what is basically causing a problem is, when I try to delete a `Project` (having a follower `f`) like this:

1. `projectService.deleteProject()`
   (there I call `project#removeFollower(f)` and then `projectRepo#delete(project)`)
2. now if I ask my `userRepo` for `User f` again (or use an old instance) it is telling me that there it is still following the project I just deleted.

Is there something I am missing to keep the other side of the relation (the followers) getting the update about the deleted project?

UPDATED OBSERVATION:

- without explicit `Cascade.MERGE & PERSIST` on `User` (not owning) side the data is out of sync and will yield in a `EntityNotFoundException`
- once I add the cascade information I get a `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bla.bla.Project`

Comment: Did you try making cascade "ALL" in Project entity?

Comment: Can add both entity classes to the question  including all the methods?And `projectService.deleteProject()` method

Comment: 1) added some more context on the entities
2) `Cascade.ALL` would mean here that once removing a relation (follower) also the respective `Project` and `User` would be deleted, no? That's why I didn't use it so far.

Comment: Can you do a `System.out.println(project.getFollowers().size());` after  the line `project.getFollowers().forEach(project::removeFollower);` and see what it is printing? You are iterating and modifying the same set and behaviour can be unpredictable.